# Mod Rewrite General Rule for mvc and Pagination?

Tags: php, .htaccess

How to create `uniq` rewrite rule for both `url`

> index.php?controller=cname&task=tname&id=10
>
> index.php?controller=cname&task=tname&page_id=20

i want to create link

```
cname/tname/10
cname/tname/20
```

both task is same but variable is different (**id** or **page_id**)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can't, because as far as these two goes:

```
cname/tname/10
cname/tname/20
```

there's no difference. How do you know when `cname/tname/10` is referring to `page_id=10`? as opposed to `id=10`?

Alternatively, you can add another identifier to differentiate them:

```
cname/tname/10
cname/tname/p20
```

This makes it much simpler:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ /index.php?controller=$1&task=$2&id=$3
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/p([0-9]+)/?$ /index.php?controller=$1&task=$2&page_id=$3
```

Comment: Thanks Jon i am very happy for your response  :)